# Retrieving GET /stats of Elastic search using NodeJS client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I can easily get this elasticsearch command (GET /_stats) response on my local environment using kibana. I however need to run the command on node.js server.
I have tried the following but it doesn't work, rather it throws error. Can anyone help me on this please?

```js
const client = new Client({
 node: process.env.ES_URL,
 auth: {
 username: process.env.ES_USER,
 password: process.env.ES_PASSWORD,
  },
});
const stats = await client.stats();
...
//The error response is TypeError: client.stats is not a function
```

PS: Using this command returns the same result on Kibana (GET _cluster/health)

```js
const {body} = await client.cluster.health({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`client.cluster.stats()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_cluster_stats) instead?